# asp.net mvc 2 web application inside a Web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, iis-7.5

I have a Asp.Net Web Site deployed as a WebSite inside IIS 7.5.

> http://localhost/WebSite

Then I have a second Asp.Net MVC 2 web application which is deployed as Sub Application inside the above WebSite. So the mvc aplication should work on the following Url.

> http://localhost/WebSite/MvcApp/

The web site works fine but when I browse the mvc Url http://localhost/WebSite/MvcApp/

It gives following error.

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web
>   server is configured to not list the
>   contents of this directory.

**UPDATE:** I have got this working. The issue was that I was missing the Web.Config inside the Views folder in the Asp.Net MVC 2 application.

Comment: The shared hosting server usually make nested directories for nested applications and they work well in my experience. But I don't know how the hosting admin setup the server. For example: I get one wwwroot directory for my domain abc.com. In wwwroot I deploy a root application files. Then I create a new application deployed in wwwroot\newapp and both applications work.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a virtual directory for the ASP.NET MVC application which will be associated to its dedicated application pool.

Comment: Inside the main web site I have added a new Application which has its own Application Pool.

Comment: How about the virtual directory? Without virtual directory an ASP.NET application cannot function properly.

Comment: Yes but I can't assign an application pool to a virtual directory.

Comment: I tried with virtual directory but it did not work with that as well

Comment: You can if the VD is an application as well

Answer (score 1):

I know I had the same problem some time ago. In my case the two applications ran a siblings, not one inside the other. The problem was the web.config in the root directory (above the two sites) conflicting with the the web.config in the seperate sites. I solved it by just deleting the root web.config (since I have nothing running in the root.

So my advice (I know it's definately not a solution) is to check for conflicts in your web.configs.

Comment: if you have a root application, what will you do?

Answer (score 0):

Is you Asp.Net MVC site running ASP.NET 4.0? If so, make sure the app pool for that MVC site is setup asp ASP.NET 4.0 and not ASP.NET 2.0.

Comment: Asp.Net MVC Site uses its own App Pool which is Asp.Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

From within IIS Manager, you can right click any folder in the tree to be converted to an application. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the mvc routing module is not executing on your requests.  You might want to check to make sure that not only is the web.config in your base web application not loading a module to supersede the routing handler, but that the web.config for your mvc application is handling routing properly.  Take a look at this article for a rundown of the dependencies for routing and how it is configured internally within iis.